# Name extracted PDF after value in cell containing a formula

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, excel-formula

I am trying to make a macro to save the active sheet as a PDF. I found the below code on the internet and made a little adjustment.

The macro is extracting the active sheet to a PDF but it doesn't name it after cell SS5 (this cell has a formula), but if we change SS5 to A2, it works.

This is code section where I think problem is:

```
CompanyN = Range("SS5").Value     
ThisFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name     
PathName = ActiveWorkbook.Path     
SvAs = "Invoice - " & CompanyN & " - " & " (payment)" & ".pdf"
```

[image]

Formula in cell SS5:

```
 =E8&" - "&IFERROR(LEFT(MID(A4,11+1,LEN(A4)),FIND("_",MID(A4,11+1,LEN(A4)))-1),"Įrašytį serijos numerį")&SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A4, LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A4, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4))), 1)) * ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4))), 0), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4))))+1, 1) * 10^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4)))/10)
```

---

FULL CODE:

```vb
Sub PrintPDF()

Call Save_PDF

End Sub

Function Save_PDF() As Boolean

' Copies sheets into new PDF file for e-mailing
Dim Thissheet As String, ThisFile As String, PathName As String
Dim SvAs As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Get File Save Name
CompanyN = Range("A2").Value
ThisFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
PathName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
SvAs = "Invoice - " & CompanyN & " - " & " (payment)" & ".pdf"

'Set Print Quality 
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

' Instruct user how to send
On Error GoTo RefLibError
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=SvAs, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
On Error GoTo 0

SaveOnly:
MsgBox "A copy of this sheet has been successfully saved as a  .pdf  file: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & SvAs & _
"Review the .pdf document. If the document does NOT look good, adjust your printing parameters, and try again."

Save_PDF = True
GoTo EndMacro

RefLibError:     MsgBox "Unable to save as PDF. Reference library not found."

Save_PDF = False
EndMacro:

End Function
```

When the code fails, it doesn't execute extraction, and writes the message from RefLibError: MsgBox "Unable to save as PDF. Reference library not found.".
Tried deleting this part, after that VBA says [ compile error: label not defined ]

Comment: How does VBA name the file when it fails?

Comment: a) Fully qualify your range references; b) if you intend to use `Thissheet` assign a value to this variable and use it for your references, c) prefix your filename with the actual path ...

Comment: When vba fails, it doesnt execute extraction, and just write message from RefLibError:     MsgBox "Unable to save as PDF. Reference library not found." . Tried deleting this part, after that VBA says [ compile error: label not defined ].